# How to call ajax mekegetrequest() function at the time of url rewriting in javaee in jsp page

Tags: windows

How to call ajax meckgetrequest() function at the time of url rewriting in javaee in jsp page

Comment: makeGetRequest();

Comment: makeGetRequest();